# $('html, body').stop().animate" not animating

Tags: jquery, html, animation, jquery-animate

I am trying to animate my HTML page so it will scroll to a  tag, so I used this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#button a').click(function( e ){
      e.preventDefault();
      var el = $( this.getAttribute('href') );
      var offs = el.offset();
      $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: offs.top-100 },500);    
   });   
});
```

HTML

```
<p id="button"><a href="#moreInfo">More Info</a></p>
<!--Some other elemts here-->

<div id="moreInfo" style="text-align: center">
```

And it will actually scroll to the desired , but it doesn't do the animation, it will only scroll without any cool transition like it should.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which "cool transition" do you expect?

Comment: The one that should do, all the body moving down, to the div.

Answer (score 0):

This should work better for you. There is no need to specify "#button". You can smooth scroll to ANY ID in your markup by writing the function the way I've shown below.  I tested my code and it works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[href^="#"]').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var target = this.hash,
  $target = $(target);

  $('html, body').stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-100
  }, 500, function () {
      window.location.hash = target;
  });
 });
});
```